# EF Core Many-To-One: Adding new Element deletes all other Entries

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a simple many-to-one relationship:

```cs
public class Company
{
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried to define my user as the following (without success):

```cs
public class User
{
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following method to add a new User to a Company:

```cs
public async Task<bool> Add(User user)
{
    try
    {
        await this.context.Set<User>().AddAsync(user);
        await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I call this method like this:

```cs
var company = await this.companyService.Get(1); // this works
if (company == null)
{
    return;
}

await this.userService.Add(
                           new User
                           {
                               CompanyId = company.Id,
                               Company = company, // I also tried to remove this line - no effect
                           });
```

My DbContext looks like this:

```cs
public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

---

Now that I have explained the scenario, here's the problem. When I add a user to a company, all entries are removed. What do I mean by "removed"? The entire table "user" is empty, without any entries. Before I add the user and inspect the `company` I can see all users. If I fetch the company again after the insertion, the property `Users` returns an empty list (not null). This also affects deletion and updating of the value. I have been sitting here with this issue for 3 days and have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 30 hours of debugging I found the problem. It had nothing to do with the EF (which I expected to a certain degree, since I literally copy and pasted the entire documentation 5 times).

Maybe someone has a similar problem, so I post my answer here, but beware that this is highly specific to my use case.

I store my currently logged in user in the [ProtectedSessionStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0) like this:

```cs
await this.protectedSessionStorage.SetAsync("user", await this.userService.Get(id));
```

For whatever reason (I searched for this for an additional 2 hours), some of my properties are ignored and not stored correctly (namely the property `Company.Users`), even though I do not use any annotations which explain this behavior. When I then load this exact user again, for some other unknown reason, the EF thinks that (because the `Company.Users` property is missing) the company does not have any users. Again, this behavior is not described in the documentation and I found literally no one with that specific problem, so I might have done something which describes this behavior.

The solution: Take [Json.NET from Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), serialize it and then store the serialized string in the protected session storage. I literally just changed this and everything works as intended. Of course I had to deserialize everything when I access the storage.

```cs
await this.protectedSessionStorage.SetAsync("user", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await this.userService.Get(id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this classes (you can ommit data annotation if you use ef core 5+)

```
public class User
{ 
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey(nameof(CompanyId ))]
   [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public  virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty(nameof(User.Company))]
  public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
 
}
```

and code

```
var company = await this.companyService.Get(1); 

await this.userService.Add(new User { CompanyId = company.Id});

public async Task<bool> Add(User user)
{
    try
    {
       context.Set<User>().Add(user);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The weird thing now is, that it looks ok in the debugger, when I check the company, add a user and then check again. But when I check (without any Add/Update/Delete called) again later (like in another view), the data is gone again. I gonna observe this a little bit more and come back again, if I found the bug.

Comment: For now it does not seem to fix my problem. If I comment out the "Add" everything works as intended. But as soon as a User is added, everything is empty.